# diamond character(�) appeared after fetch url in google script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

newbb got a question about character problem between google and webpage table.

I'm using google sheet and script to get a table from a opened website to google spreadsheet.

the page url is below (um.. I have reputation limit)

```
http://www.mogef.go.kr/system/korea/board/photo/photo.jsp?bid=341
```

At first time I used google spreadsheet function 'importhtml'.

The tables works fine but the language is changed weird. 
I've changed google language option but didn't work.

[picture of character problem at google sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VPYPQ.jpg)

so I trying to get HTML of table in google script by following api fetch example and

I thought this problem comes from charset.. encoding.. or something

so added an option about charset ('euc-kr' from the page HTML source)

```
 //in google apps script   
function myFunction() {
      var option = 
      {
      "contentType" : "charset=euc-kr"
      };
       var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch("~~~url~~~", option);
     Logger.log(response.getContentText());
    }
```

And It success to take HTML as text

but the language(same above language) looks like this..

[diamond characters](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Fe9D.jpg)

How can I solve this problem..? I need normal text table or HTML text in google sheet or script. without MS excel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the docs you can pass a charset to getContentText:

```
response.getContentText('EUC-KR')
```

This should return the characters correctly.

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/http-response#getcontenttextcharset

Comment: Thanks problem solved! after change the code following your api link and  the result HTML looks fine. again thank you.

Comment: You're welcome, glad I could help. As a bonus for me I've got the korean fonts installed now :)